# If I don't want to call clean_<fieldname>() method, can I do it?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-1.4, django-validation

Django: If I don't want to call clean_() method, can I do it?

```
class myForm(forms.Form):
    userId = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False,)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False,)

    def clean_userId(self):
        if 'userId' in self.cleaned_data:
            if not re.search(r'^\w+$', self.cleaned_data['userId']):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid ID')
            try:
                User.objects.get(username=self.cleaned_data['userId'])
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                return self.cleaned_data['userId']
            raise raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid ID')
        else:
            raise raise forms.ValidationError('Invalid ID')
```

Sometimes, I want to use Form validation in order to validate only 'email' field.

Like below:

```
>>> form = myForm({'email':'abc@com'})
>>> form.cleaned_data['email']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'myForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'
>>> print form.errors
<ul class="errorlist"><li>workers<ul class="errorlist"><li>Invalid ID</li></ul>
```

Is there the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
form = myForm({'email':'abc@com'})
try:
    form.clean_email()
except forms.ValidationError:
    #do whatever
else:
    #do whatever
```

`is_valid()` will call `clean` on everything, so just call whatever `clean` method you want.

You could also just have two different forms or a form that inherits from another, this would be a lot better IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need define `clean_userId()` or `clean_email()`, just define `clean()`, do all in that method of Form.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # fields

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(MyForm, self).clean()
        email = cleaned_data.get('email')

        # do some validation

        return cleaned_data
```

Before you access `cleaned_data`, remember call `form.is_valid()`.

Comment: Umm... By the way, do i have to validate all of other fields in '# do some validation' section?

Comment: Can I use validation in other section?

Comment: write your function to do that.